# How to get the binary execution result in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

A binary program is define in the environment variable. When run "set", I see **CHECK_MASTER=/usr/local/bin/check_master**.

In the terminal, run $CHECK_MASTER, we can see 0 or 1 showing on the terminal.
In shell script, I can run /usr/local/bin/check_master | tee /dev/tty and the result shows on the terminal which is 0 or 1.

Question:
(1) How do I get the result from executing **/usr/local/bin/check_master** and assign the result to a variable like $VAR in the shell script?
(2) Similar to (1), how can I use **$CHECK_MASTER** rather than using the file path in the shell script?

I have tried redirect stdout, stderr, VAR=$($CHECK_MASTER). None of them work.

Comment: zsh? bash? ksh? tcsh? eshell?...

Comment: It is "bash" shell.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it looks as if check_master will send 0 or 1 to stderr. Redirection of stderr to stdout should help:

```
CHECK_MASTER=...
VAR=$($CHECK_MASTER 2>&1)
```

Comment: I have tried this one and it did not work. However, I tried VAR=$(/usr/local/bin/check_master 2>&1) and it worked. It seems that $CHECK_MASTER will be treated differently.

Comment: How did you 'set' CHECK_MASTER ? It should be exported (e.g. envvar) to get passed to the sub shell. The 'set' will show both types.